# Errors when including Entity Data Model across referenced projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Decided to take a dive into recreating a website so that it's an ASP.NET MVC web application. We were originally using the Entity Framework for it, figured to still use it since it works nicely enough. When doing some reading, noticed the there is no such thing as the App_Code/ folder for MVC applications, and that most people were creating a class library for their needs like that. So what I ended up doing was creating my MVC application and a class library, both in the same solution, and the MVC application was referencing the class library. The class library has my EDMX Entity Data Model file in it since some of my classes reference it and I thought that it would be easiest to have it in the library to reference. So [here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJp9a.jpg) to what my solution layout is. But when I build and run the website, I get an error on a page that would reference the Entity Data Model. [Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvWY5.jpg) of what the error is.

So I thought, what if I placed the EDMX into my models folder since the error looks like it's complaining about not finding the entities. [Here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkFx3.jpg) of my solution now with the move. But now, I'm getting a different error ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udHNi.jpg)). I'm kind of at a loss as to where to go from here. Is the way I have everything laid out and designed the proper and most efficient way to do it? If not could someone give me some advice?

Thanks, it's really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to have the edmx in a class library and reference if from your main project. The first error is likely due to an incorrect connection string (check this [blog post](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/)) but you may also have changed the build action of the edmx file somehow, make sure it is "Entity Deploy".

The second error is probably because you copied the edmx from your class library into the Models folder and it is still referencing the old namespace. To fix that, open the edmx in designer view and click on the background. One of the properties in the property window is Namespace, make sure that's set to the new place you want to keep it.

**Edit:**
Some things to try:

- Clean and rebuild the project
- Delete the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder referenced in the error message
- Double check your cshtml files for old references to URG_MVC.Models namespace. For example, the line in the error should be `IEnumerable<URGLibrary.Proposal>`
- Right click the edmx file and select Run Custom Tool to regenerate the model files

Comment: thanks for the response. I fixed the first part, but in doing so, I get the second error I was getting, even though the EDMX file is in the class library, with the correct namespace (the namespace of the class library).

Comment: The error text is probably different now if you moved it to the class library. Can you edit your post with a picture of the new error, a picture of your current solution layout and a picture of the properties window for the model, the one with the namespace in. Should be able to help you out from that.

Comment: Here's a link to the album containing the images of what you requested: http://imgur.com/a/yx9iD

Comment: Thanks, the namespace on the EDMX looks correct at least. Edited my answer with some things to try.

Comment: Keep your EDMX in the class library.  Make sure that you have the connection string for EF in your MVC web.config. you may need to Add Reference to the EF libraries in the MVC application as well.

Comment: It was the third one, fixing the IEnumerable references. Thanks a ton man!